Set Xcode “Library Search Paths” form cmake?
After I configured the project from Qt Creator, in Xcode I need to manually go to project BUILD SETTINGS, locate LIBRARY SEARCH PATHS and set some stuff manually…
can this be automated from cmake?
I need to set followings paths:

Unfortunately I tried to google up as much as I could, however google does not give me anything
Thank you for any hints.

You are probably looking for target_link_directories command. However, as you could find in the documentation, usage of this command should be avoided in flavor to use absolute path to libraries in target_link_libraries command.

as @Tsyvarev suggested, final solution be like:
target_link_directories(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos")

just this one line basicaly handles everything, other are not needed
